# how to set priority in openmp?

Tags: linux, openmp

I am creating three different sections in openmp and these three sections will be run by three different threads. I want to set the priority of one particular section which will be run by one thread . How to do this?

Comment: You are mistaking OpenMP for the general-purpose parallel computing paradigm which it is not.

Answer (score 1):

see [Missing OpenMP feature: Thread Priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671902/missing-openmp-feature-thread-priority) about setting priority within the openmp loop. Though I think any priority setting code is going to be platform dependent

have a look here [Equivalent of SetThreadPriority on Linux (pthreads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876342/equivalent-of-setthreadpriority-on-linux-pthreads) for linux specific